# Stylelint error - Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration

Tags: css, reactjs, eslint, stylelint

[image]

[image]

Stylelint gives me this error when in iconfont.css, I'm importing it like this.

How can i make it work?

Comment: This might be a bug in stylelint. See https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/4761#issuecomment-627663760